# Is there a way to add user exceptions in Microsoft 365 DLP policies?

Tags: microsoft365, microsoft-information-protection, o365security-compliance

We have a requirement to exclude users in the specified group from DLP. How can this be done currently in Microsoft 365 Data protection policies?
Also, if this feature is not available currently than will this be available in future?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can exclude users or groups from DLP policies. Open up the existing DLP policies and you will have an exclude button.